# How does stl containers' `less` parameter works?

Tags: c++, stl

Let take `map` for this example.

I set the map object: `map<const char*, int, compare> a`, as `compare` is the following:

```
struct compare : public std::binary_function<const char*, const char*, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const char* a, const char* b) {
        return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};
```

What have I done here? How did I overload this operator? Isn't that unary operator?

It's working, but I'm not sure that I really know what I've written here.

this is the complete code:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct compare : public std::binary_function<const char*, const char*, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const char* a, const char* b) {
        return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    map<const char*, int, compare> a;

    a["Mike"] = 5;
    a["Tre"] = 3;
    a["Billie"] = 20;

    for(map<const char*, int, compare>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        cout << (*it).first << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Technically, your `operator()` member function should be marked `const`.

Comment: Those are `std` containers.  `STL` is the name of the library that inspired the  `std` container and algorithm libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compare` definition permits the following:

```
compare cmp;
bool result = cmp("foo", "bar");  // Two arguments, therefore not unary!
```

Thus `std::map` can use it to determine the relative ordering of pairs of elements.  This is required in order to construct a binary search tree behind-the-scenes.

Comment: And is this how the `map` object use my template argument?

Comment: @user1798362: Roughly speaking, yes.  With a comparison operation, one can construct and search a binary search tree.

Answer (score 1):

> What have I done here?

You created a [*function object*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) - an object that provides an implementation for the `operator ()`, and supplied its class to instantiate the `std::map` template.

> How did I overload this operator?

You provided its public implementation (note that `struct` makes its members `public` by default).

> Isn't that unary operator?

No. A unary operator takes one operand; your operator takes two operands, and is, therefore, binary.